# What happened to isZoomedIgnoreProgrammaticZoom?

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I am using dygraph 1.1.0 since, well... forever :-)
Now I wanted to have a look at dygraph 2.0.0 and of course expected some migration to do.
Now, the only error I actually get after simply replacing the *.js files is:

```
 Uncaught invalid option isZoomedIgnoreProgrammaticZoom  dygraph.js:4448
```

When I remove this option from my code, everything still seems to work.

I could not find anything about the option in the new docs, so my question in:

What happened to isZoomedIgnoreProgrammaticZoom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That option [was removed](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/pull/812#issue-197649058) in the 2.0 release.

That option affected the behavior of the `isZoomed()` method. If you're not using that method, you can remove the option without changing anything. If you are, it should be possible to get whatever behavior you want by using other methods in the [dygraphs API](http://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html). But I'd need more specifics to help.

Comment: Hello again and still: Thanks for the great framework. It was (and maybe still is) the mot performant one I have tested and not as bloated as the other (esp. the commercial) ones. I will check my usages of isZoomed and ask again, if I encounter any problems. Maybe the error message could incorporate this hint.